# Cyclic dependency in SBT with flyway, jooq and compile

Tags: sbt, flyway

This is the problem I have. Flyway applies a schema to a database, and jOOq generates code from that schema. Compile compiles the code. So this is how it looks like:

```
Flyway runs -> jooq runs -> compilation
```

The problem is that, `flyway` for some reason, depends on `runtime:fullClasspath`, which in turn depends on `compile:compile`. I understand that `flyway` depends on `compile` for any Java migrations, but we don't have any Java migrations. Is there a way for `flyway` to depend only on `runtime:dependencyClasspath` and not on `fullClasspath`, so that I can define that,

```
(codegen in jOOQ) dependsOn flywayMigrate
compile dependsOn (codegen in jOOQ)
```

For some projects, we were facing similar problems with the gradle plugin, and it was solved with [Flyway Gradle plugin - Circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129694/flyway-gradle-plugin-circular-dependency)

I have no idea what to do with `sbt`.

Comment: This should be fixed with the flyway 4 release, whenever that happens: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/979

Comment: ... and the workaround until then is to put flyway in its own sbt subproject.